# How to make the function pointer work in this case?

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to write an example code for the following line of code:

```c
int (*(*foo)(const void*))[3];
```

I got this code from [here](https://cdecl.org/) (at each refresh of the website you get a different piece of code and there is a finite set of them so by reloading a couple of times you will get my example). I wanted to see out of curiosity is it even possible to write some code that would make this line work.

Here is what I wrote so far:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int* goo(const void * ptr) {
    int* ret = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    if (!ret)
        return NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        ret[i] = i;

    return ret;
}

int doo() { return 0; }

int main(void) {

    //NOTE: Following 2 lines have syntax errors

    int (*(*foo)(const void*))[3] = &goo;

    int* values = foo(goo(doo));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        printf("%d", values[i]);
    }

    free(values);

    return 0;
}
```

If I understood correctly, `foo` should *be* some function that receives as an argument another function and returns an int array of size 3. The problem is I don't know how to make `foo` in this case point to a function or even how to get the int array.

Is it even possible to make this line of code work?

Comment: [Your code fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fa79877d132cc63).  Second, *Is it even possible to make this line of code work?* -- code like this is seldom, if ever written in an actual program.

Comment: this is why std::function exists

Comment: @pm100 Why is that so?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for the quick reply. I'm aware that the code doesn't compile and that this is very very rarely used but out of fun wanted to try to make it work. I thought that it was obvious from my post that the code probably has syntax errors but I'll add this to the question. I wanted to show where I stopped coding. Nevertheless thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

> If I understood correctly, foo should be some function

`foo` is a pointer to a function.

> that receives as an argument another function

No, the parameter type of the function that `foo` points to must be a pointer to const void  i.e. `const void*`. A pointer to void is an object pointer. It can point to an object of any type.

Functions are not objects, but on some systems, pointers to functions can be reinterpreted as pointers to void.

> and returns an int array of size 3.

No; Return types cannot be arrays. The function must return a pointer to an array of 3 ints i.e. `int(*)[3]`.

> Is it even possible to make this line of code work?

Here is an example program that uses such `foo`. It doesn't make much sense, but that's because the goal is to use an obscure function pointer:

```
#include<iostream>

int arr[] {
    1,
    2,
    3,
};

int (*goo(const void*))[3] {
    return &arr;
}


int main() {
    int (*(*foo)(const void*))[3] = &goo;
    int (*values)[3]  = foo(nullptr);

    for (int i : *values) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

We can greatly improve readability by introducing type aliases:

```
using IntArr3 = int[3];
using FooFun = IntArr3*(const void*);

IntArr3* goo(const void*) {
    return &arr;
}


int main() {
    FooFun* foo = &goo;
    IntArr3* values = foo(nullptr);

    for (int i : *values) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```